# How do I find the output for getstring listed here : https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/enrol/instances.php

Tags: php, xampp, moodle, spelling

I'm currently working on Moodle to change the spelling of enrol to enroll. I've completed almost every single screen except two places. Here is the code [Github](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/enrol/instances.php). To dig more, I need to know how do I find where to find the output of line 47 and what is the output? I have very little knowledge on coding, please excuse if the question is not clear

Comment: This sounds like something that would be achieved a lot more easily by installing the 'en_us' language pack (which already covers this and most other variations between British/Australian and American English).

Answer (score 1):

`get_string(STRING_NAME, COMPONENT)` takes english strings from **/lang/en/COMPONENT.php**

In your example, you would find the output for `get_string('enrolmentinstances', 'enrol')` in **/lang/en/enrol.php** (see https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/lang/en/enrol.php#L60 - `$string['enrolmentinstances'] = 'Enrolment methods';`)